# How to create a table in sql server like other table?

Tags: sql-server, inheritance, sql-like

I want to create a table like another table in SQL Server.

In Postgres I used to create it with this request:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (LIKE table1  INCLUDING ALL) INHERITS (table1)
```

Comment: Some sample data and desired output would be nice, even if answer be possible without this.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `create table like table1` **and** `inherits (table1)` together does not make any sense.

Comment: Script `table1` in SSMS (right-click the table, script > CREATE), change the name to `table2`, and execute script.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('table1', 'U') IS NULL BEGIN
   SELECT TOP 0 * INTO table1 FROM table2
END
```

This will clone the column definition of `table2` in `table1` without inserting any data (because of the `top 0`).

Then you have to create the PK, UK, FK for the `table1`. For this purpose you can check: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3443/script-all-primary-keys-unique-constraints-and-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database-using-tsql/

With this resource you can generate an `ALTER TABLE` script to add all PK, UK, FK in a variable and run it like:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

Comment: @Mahamakni Check my update with the UK, PK, FK scripting from an existing table.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *    
INTO table2
FROM table1 where 1=2
```

- `SELECT *` = select all columns
- `INTO`= place of set
- `FROM` = place to lookup,
- `WHERE 1=2` = filter criteria

Comment: Add some detail in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
select top 0 * into x from y
```

will give you an empty shell of a table with no data exactly defined as the original table minus all the indexes , constraints etc